# Seemingly inconsistent RuntimeWarning using numpy arange

Tags: python, numpy, warnings

When my friend runs the following code, it gives a RuntimeWarning and returns "inf". However, if I run this same code, it executes without a warning and returns a value.

```
import numpy as np
total = 0
k = 10**6
arr = np.arange(k, 0, -1)
for i in arr:
    total += 1/(i**2)
print(total)
```

This is her output:

```
\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:7: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in long_scalars
  import sys
inf
```

Replacing np.arange() with the built-in range() solves the problem, and she gets the same output as me.

My question is: what is causing this inconsistency between her output and mine? Additionally, why is she seeing a difference when using np.arange vs range, while for me the output is the same?

We are both using python 3.7.4 via Anaconda, and numpy 1.16.5, on 64-bit Windows 10.

Comment: first use `print()` to see values for `arange()` and `range()`.

Comment: same issue W10 x64 Python 3.7

Comment: it works correctly for both on LInux Mint (64-bit), Python 3.7.7 (64-bit) numpy 1.18.4, (without Anaconda). The same Python 2.7.17 (64-bit), numpy 1.16.6 Do you use `64-bit` Python on both computers?

Comment: @furas Just checked. We're both using ``64-bit`` Python.

Comment: @furas printing appears to show the same values for both arange() and range(), just with arange() as a numpy array of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its to do with what data type Numpy infers when you create `arr`. For me Numpy infered that I wanted `np.int32` & that is just not big enough to hold (10**6)**2 so you end up with an `inf` value.

If you explcitly declare the data type as say `np.float64` the problem resolves itself.

```
arr = np.arange(k, 0, -1, dtype=np.float64)
```

Comment: Thanks, that does explain the issue on her end. But I don't understand why I am not seeing the same behavior. With the same version of numpy, why would numpy apparently infer different data types between my friend and I?

Comment: @L.N.M what value are you getting?

Comment: 1.6449330668487263 @DrBwts

Comment: I must admit that's very odd. For W10 x64 machines the default should be `int32` ie a `c long int` as opposed to a `c long long int` which your machine seems to be using.